# Comparing two EditText values in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make an app where the user enters a word into an EditText box. Then, they enter something into another box and it checks to see if they are the same word. Here's the code that I used:

```
         String word = textfield1.getText().toString();
         String answer = textfield2.getText().toString();

          textfield2.setText(textfield2.getText().toString()); 

          if(word == answer){

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }else 
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

However, it always says that the two strings aren't the same even if they are. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think object may compare the `==` ,if you want compare the two string  use `equals` and `equalignorecase` likethat functionlity.

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare strings with the `==` operator.

Use `.equals()` instead:

```
if(word.equals(answer)) {
    //do whatever
}
```

Comment: Yes . Thanks for string explained hint.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` for comparing content of both string variables.:

```
  if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
String word = textfield1.getText().toString();
String answer = textfield2.getText().toString();

if(answer.contentEquals(word)){
  // Do something if equals
}

else{
  // Do something if not equals
}
```

Comment: It's workin.Thanks  I used if(!question.contentEquals(ans)) for negatve level.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is using TextUtils:

```
if(TextUtils.equals(textfield1.getText(),textfield2.getText())){
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 if(word.contentEquals(answer)){

     }
```

Use

```
 if(word.equals(answer))
```

as we cant compare strings with  **Equal to (==)** operator

Try This::

```
String word = textfield1.getText().toString();
             String answer = textfield2.getText().toString();



              if(word.equals(answer)){

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }else 
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```